# Dropzone js The file preview field must be a file of type: jpeg, pdf, png, jpg, docx, mkv, mp4, mp3, zip, rar. in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, dropzone.js

I have 2 controllers for comment. The first one is Comment Controller, the function is to create comments and store comments and attachment to database. The second controller is FileUploadController, this controller function is, when user try to upload attachments on dropzone js, it'll store the attachments to the temporary path .When i try to upload my attachments to dropzone, i got a message on network like "The file preview field must be a file of type: jpeg, pdf, png, jpg, docx, mkv, mp4, mp3, zip, rar.". I want to upload my attachments, then when it goes to the temporary path, i want to create the comments. If i already create the comments and want to post that. The temporary path will move to attachments path, and grab the url to store to the database.I dont use ajax cuz i cant use it sorry.

This is my code on FileUploadController

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // Validasi
        $request->validate([
            'file' => 'nullable|mimes:jpeg,pdf,png,jpg,docx,mkv,mp4,mp3,zip,rar|max:5048',
        ]);
        

        $file = $request->file('file_preview');
        if ($file) {
            $tempPath = $file->store('temporary', 'public');

            return response()->json(['tempPath' => $tempPath]);
        }

        return response()->json(['error' => 'File upload failed.']);
    }
```

And this is my dropzone js Scripts

```
<script>
        Dropzone.options.dropzone = {
            url: "{{ route('upload') }}",
            paramName: "file[]",
            maxFiles: 5,
            maxFilesize: 5, // MB
            uploadMultiple: true,
            acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.pdf,.png,.jpg,.docx,.mkv,.mp4,.mp3,.zip,.rar",
            init: function(){
                var submitButton = document.querySelector("#button-submit");
                dropzone = this;
    
                this.on("success", function(file, response) {
                    console.log(response); // Tangani respons dari server (opsional)
                });
    
                this.on("error", function(file, response) {
                    return false; // Tangani pesan kesalahan dari server (opsional)
                });
                
                dropzone.on("complete", function(file) {
                    dropzone.removeFile(file);    
                });
            }
        };
    </script>
```

This is my form

```
<div class="mx-xl-5 mx-3 mb-3">
    <form class="rounded-2 shadow-sm dropzone" method="POST" action="{{ route('comment.store', $helper->id) }}" id="dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
            <div class="form-floating">
                <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Leave a comment here" name="comments" id="floatingTextarea"></textarea>
                <label for="floatingTextarea text-center">Comments</label>
            </div>
            {{-- Button submit --}}
            <input type="submit" value="post" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary px-3 py-2 fs-4 mt-3 rounded-2" id="button-submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

this is my CommentController

```
public function store(Request $request, $id)
    {
        // Validasi
        $request->validate([
            'comments' => 'required',
            'file' => 'nullable|mimes:jpeg,pdf,png,jpg,docx,mkv,mp4,mp3,zip,rar|max:5048',
        ]);

        $helper = Helper::find($id);

        $comment = Comment::create([
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'comments' => $request->input('comments'),
            'helper_id' => $helper->id,
        ]);

        $commentId = $request->input('comments'); // Mendapatkan commentId dari input

        $attachmentPath = $request->input('file'); // Dapatkan path temporary dari input

        if ($attachmentPath) {
            $attachmentFilename = basename($attachmentPath);
            $newAttachmentPath = 'attachments/' . $attachmentFilename;
            Storage::move($attachmentPath, $newAttachmentPath);

            // Simpan informasi lampiran ke dalam database sesuai commentId
            AttachmentComment::create([
                'comment_id' => $commentId,
                'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
                'id_tiket' => $helper->unique_id,
                'file_preview' => Storage::url($newAttachmentPath),
            ]);
        }
```

Thank you who answered my question

Comment: What file type would you like to upload ACTUALLY  ?

Comment: i try to upload .jpeg file and .jpg file, it didnt go to the temp path